# How to print only PDF pages with searched text

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

In a PDF Document with 200> pages, I want to print only the ones containing a given search text.
However it seems that Acrobat Reader is not able to do this. I can print only selected pages, but I can not select all pages with the keyword.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem (other than manually printing all matches).

I also tried Foxit Reader but I also wasn't able to do it
(The solution should be free if possible)